# HDD on Caddy does not show in Windows 11 but visible in BIOS and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, bios, windows-11

I have Dell Inspiron 5570 and had 1TB HDD preinstalled. I removed CD ROM and installed caddy with 1TB HDD and replaced the HDD with SSD 240GB and also added 120GB M2.SSD. Now the HDD is not showing in Windows 11 but I can see it in BIOS.

> Here's the screenshot of the BIOS

[image]

[image]

> Here's the screenshot of Device Manager disk drives

[image]

> Here's the screenshot of Disk Management screen

[image]

Now, when I use a Ubuntu live bootable USB and check the drives in folder view or GParted, I can clearly see the HDD and also I can use it normally.

I also formatted the HDD with NTFS and is GPT. Still no clue why I cannot see it in Windows 11.

Please help.

Comment: Do you see any device in Device Manager with an exclamation mark, if yes what info that it have?

Comment: Is there some kind of Intel RST management tool installed? Maybe see if it list the drive and has some kind of option to enable/disable drives? (Just some wild guess, not that I've actually heard of something like that.) Also consider updating the RST driver.

Comment: @YisroelTech I don't see any exclamation mark in device manager

Comment: @TomYan RST management isn't installed. When I go to Dell drivers page and put in my model and windows version, it says RST is not compatible with my laptop

Comment: Try uninstalling the controllers in Device Manager under *IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers* and reboot (after all of them are uninstalled, if there is more than one). This will force the controller to reinstall from fresh.

Comment: I don't see any IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers options in device manager window

Comment: That'd be odd. What do you have under **Storage Controllers**? Maybe put a screenshot of the whole Device Manager

Answer (score -2):

If it shows in the BIOS and other OSs, then Windows is the cause. I'll throw these points out of nowhere:

- In the Disk Management, right click the D drive and assign it to a folder.
- I suspect it's a partition issue. Try to delete all partitions on that drive including the Healthy EFI Partition, maybe it'll work. Deleting a partition will erase everything on the drive.
- If the drive shows on other OSs on the same laptop, then it probably has to do with Dell's software/drivers so that Windows only recognizes a CDROM from that SATA port. It's not profitable if you can extend the storage without paying them directly. Check if the drive shows on another Windows device. If the drive shows then my hypothesis is correct.